# DatePicker Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, ssl, datepicker

I have added an SSL certificate to my Wordpress site and all of the pages show secure with the exception of one. On that page, I use a jQuery DatePicker that seems to prevent my page from being shown as secure.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='st_jquery_ui_style-css'  href='https://example.com/includes/css/jquery-ui.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://example.com/includes/js/jquery-ui.js?ver=4.9.4'></script>
```

`$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          altField: "#lastInspected",
    });`

When I remove the DatePicker by deleting the above script, the page shows as secure. I thought the image icons loaded in the calendar load may be loading from an insecure location, but those seem fine. However, when I hover over to reveal the hover state of the datepicker next and back arrows, the inspector given me the same warning.

The warning I get does not point to any url request that is being made over http:// so it is difficult to find what is happening. It just says "Loading mixed (insecure) display content “http://example.com/” on a secure page
[Learn More]"

Does anyone know what I might try to ensure my page shows as secured?

Comment: We need to see code in order to help.  What does your `<link>` tag for `jquery-ui.css`and your `<script>` tag for `jquery-ui.js` look like?  If either one is loaded over `http://` then that's your problem.

Comment: I updated explanation with my best guess at what is relevant. Thanks!

Comment: What browser do you use?  In chrome it will tell you what resource was blocked as mixed content in the network tab under dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Firefox, which did not give me details of the warnings. Once I switched over to Chrome, it had the same warnings, but told me more. The DatePicker was pulling in images/icons that were not in the correct location on my server. It was not that they were using http://, it was simply that they did not exist. Very silly. Thanks!